# Define object position at runtime with javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, graph

I'm making an application with javaFX. The application consists of creating a kind of "graph" from the user.
The user through a button creates a node (is created by a circle with JAVAFX figure) and associates it to a variable, repeating the process, creating another node, and so on. Now I need to figure out how to define the node position inside a specially reserved space. Obviously, after creating nodes, through another button, the user creates the arcs (is created by a line connecting two nodes) associated with the nodes, thus defining a graph.
My problem is that I do not understand how to indicate the position of lines that will act as arcs in my graph.

Please help me.I'm not very experienced and I'm trying to tackle this problem.

Comment: Please update your question giving a small (runnable) example of what you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to tell us what is your "reserved space"? If it's a Canvas then you can draw shapes with Canva's GraphicsContext.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.fillOval(10, 60, 30, 30);
gc.fillArc(10, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN);
```

Otherwise if you are working inside a pane with layout you need to know if the components are managed or not. For example inside a Pane or AnchorPane the node's automatic layout is disabled, thus you need to specify their layoutX and layoutY by yourself (+ node dimensions) like :

```
node.setLayoutX(12);
node.setLayoutY(222);
node.setPrefWidth(500);
node.setPrefHeight(500);
```

If you are using a pane like VBox which manage the layout of it's nodes you need to set the nodes inside the pane to be unmanaged in order for you to apply specific transformations. You can do that just by setting :

```
node.setManaged(false)
```

I will not recommend you to use Canvas cause handling the shapes will be very hard, for example if you need to remove something you probably have to clear everything and redraw only the visible shapes.

Well I had some time so here is a small example ( It might not be the optimal solution, but you can take is as a reference)

**GraphTest**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GraphTest extends Application {

    private double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
    private double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

    private Group root = new Group();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        GraphNode node1 = createNode("A", 100, 100, Color.RED);
        GraphNode node2 = createNode("B", 300, 200, Color.GREEN);
        GraphNode node3 = createNode("C", 80, 300, Color.PURPLE);

        connectNodes(node1, node2, "C1");

        connectNodes(node3, node1, "C2");
        connectNodes(node3, node2, "C3");

        root.getChildren().addAll(node1, node2, node3);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void connectNodes(GraphNode node1, GraphNode node2, String edgeText) {

        Line edgeLine = new Line(node1.getCenterX(), node1.getCenterY(), node2.getCenterX(), node2.getCenterY());
        Label edgeLabel = new Label(edgeText);

        node1.addNeighbor(node2);
        node2.addNeighbor(node1);

        node1.addEdge(edgeLine, edgeLabel);
        node2.addEdge(edgeLine, edgeLabel);

        root.getChildren().addAll(edgeLine, edgeLabel);

    }

    private GraphNode createNode(String nodeName, double xPos, double yPos, Color color) {
        GraphNode node = new GraphNode(nodeName, xPos, yPos, color);
        node.setOnMousePressed(circleOnMousePressedEventHandler);
        node.setOnMouseDragged(circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);

        return node;
    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
            orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();

            GraphNode node = (GraphNode) t.getSource();

            orgTranslateX = node.getTranslateX();
            orgTranslateY = node.getTranslateY();
        }
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
            double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
            double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

            GraphNode node = (GraphNode) t.getSource();

            node.setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            node.setTranslateY(newTranslateY);

            updateLocations(node);
        }
    };

    private void updateLocations(GraphNode node) {

        ArrayList<GraphNode> connectedNodes = node.getConnectedNodes();

        ArrayList<Line> edgesList = node.getEdges();

        for (int i = 0; i < connectedNodes.size(); i++) {

            GraphNode neighbor = connectedNodes.get(i);
            Line l = edgesList.get(i);

            l.setStartX(node.getCenterX());

            l.setStartY(node.getCenterY());

            l.setEndX(neighbor.getCenterX());

            l.setEndY(neighbor.getCenterY());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**GraphNode**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class GraphNode extends StackPane {

    private Circle circle;
    private Label text;

    private ArrayList<GraphNode> connectedNodesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Line> edgesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Label> edgesLabelList = new ArrayList<>();

    private double radius = 50.0;

    public GraphNode(String name, double xPos, double yPos, Color color) {

        circle = new Circle(radius, color);
        text = new Label(name);
        text.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);

        setLayoutX(xPos);
        setLayoutY(yPos);

        getChildren().addAll(circle, text);
        layout();
    }

    public void addNeighbor(GraphNode node) {
        connectedNodesList.add(node);
    }

    public void addEdge(Line edgeLine, Label edgeLabel) {
        edgesList.add(edgeLine);
        edgesLabelList.add(edgeLabel);

        // If user move the node we should translate the edge labels as well
        // one way of doing that is by make a custom binding to the layoutXProperty as well
        // as to layoutYProperty. We will listen for changes to the currentNode translate properties
        // and for changes of our neighbor.


        edgeLabel.layoutXProperty().bind(new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                bind(translateXProperty());
                bind(connectedNodesList.get(connectedNodesList.size() - 1).translateXProperty());
            }

            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {

                // We find the center of the line to translate the text
                double width = edgeLine.getEndX() - edgeLine.getStartX();

                return edgeLine.getStartX() + width / 2.0;
            }
        });

        edgeLabel.layoutYProperty().bind(new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                bind(translateYProperty());
                bind(connectedNodesList.get(connectedNodesList.size() - 1).translateYProperty());
            }

            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {

                double width = edgeLine.getEndY() - edgeLine.getStartY();
                return edgeLine.getStartY() + width / 2.0;
            }
        });

    }

    public ArrayList<GraphNode> getConnectedNodes() {
        return connectedNodesList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Line> getEdges() {
        return edgesList;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return getLayoutX() + getTranslateX();
    }

    public double getY() {
        return getLayoutY() + getTranslateY();
    }

    public double getCenterX() {
        return getX() + radius;
    }

    public double getCenterY() {
        return getY() + radius;
    }

}
```

And the Output would look like that :

[image: Graph]

You can move the nodes with your mouse and you will see all the labels will follow the shapes locations ( Cicle , Lines )

Comment: this is a real example,I did it all with SCENE BUILDER, but unfortunately I "played" with visible and invisible node / arcs.
In the sense that I have drawn 5 nodes and all possible links, and then only made visible the node and arcs required by the user. Of course this strategy is not good and I need to figure out how to position them within that layout (not a canvas). The pictures are sorted.  1) https://ibb.co/kFLeOw
           2) https://ibb.co/fcbawG
3) https://ibb.co/kuVeOw
4) https://ibb.co/kKB8GG
5) https://ibb.co/eeVeOw
6) https://ibb.co/nu6awG
7) https://ibb.co/gHzjqb

Comment: So you are using a layout, in that case you need to set all your nodes to be .setManaged(false) and then programmatically you can set their location by calling setLayoutX & setLayoutY. Of course I would suggests to implement movement by drag and drop have a look here : http://java-buddy.blogspot.gr/2013/07/javafx-drag-and-move-something.html

Comment: I hope I can do it this way, but for the arcs between two nodes how can I do it?

Comment: hmm by creating custom objects which each object represents a Node in your graph containing info about it's x & y position and a list with all connections ( nodes ) you can draw lines ( or arcs ) between two nodes at runtime depending on their location. I will update my answer giving an example later.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, in fact my intention is to completely modify my program. By creating a node name object, each object contains information about its position (X and Y coordinates) and other node objects to which it is linked.
Conceptually, the solution should be perfect. But the problem in my opinion is to put them inside the layout so they do not give any problems and especially draw the strings that link them.
Can you give me a practical example of use as soon as you have time? Thank you very much.

Comment: Here you go. The refactoring I will leave it to you, but you will get the main idea. As i said in the post I can't guarantee that's the optimal way although we you get the main idea ;)

Comment: If I want to associate a letter to each node, which will be located within the node itself (using a JavaFX Label) and a further letter (always using a javaFX Label) to associate with each arc, can it be done? Like this  https://ibb.co/gHzjqb . Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes you can. All you need is to add the labels upon creation and connections and of course translate their position relative to the node and edge.

Comment: @Applefriend I make some changes in order to implement labels on nodes and edges. I am pretty sure you can handle the rest. Adding MouseListener on nodes to change the Labels at runtime will be easy to accomplish, I hope the example above will help you get started. Are still having issue ?

Comment: Thank you so much, while I'm reusing this code for my application, you've been really nice and helpful. I'm having trouble erasing a node that is connected to one or more nodes, I just managed to clear the node but the arches remain. Can you give me a hand? this is the situation 1) https://ibb.co/mngLLb
2) https://ibb.co/fuSXYw
3) https://ibb.co/cRczDw

Comment: @Applefriend I would like to help but this post is already answer the question and keep adding more requirements will confuse people with the same issue as yours. So if the problem about moving object at runtime is fixed then mark the answer as correct and later start a new post asking help about erasing a node at runtime (if you can't find a post already answering your question), if you do i would gladly help you with anything else you might have.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice. However, I would like to understand how to set the layoutX and layoutY of the node inside the layout. I've been thinking of using the random class to give them the X and Y coordinates, but it does not look like a good method, often when I create them appear one on the other, although I can move them not so much. https://ibb.co/ftSNiw

Comment: Using random coordinates is not a good idea. I would suggest to set a mouse listener on your pane showing the coordinates of the mouse and do give the user one of these options : 
1. If he want to add a new node with a button, he should set the X and Y coordinates before he add the node.
2. By pressing the left or right mouse click to show a menu asking the user if he want to add a node there.
3. Create a list showing all the options he has ( for example he can add nodes or text or something else like a tool bar ) and then by dragging the component directly to the pane.

Comment: wanting to use the toolbar I created like I could pick the coordinates directly to the user without obviously writing them down? I use a dialog to create the node, I think I have previously provided some screenshots, how can I modify this solution without distorting everything? I would understand how to make them appear in the dedicated space avoiding overlapping. thank you

Comment: If you do not want to ask the user to give the coordinates inside the dialog upon node creation, then you need to find an empty space by yourself, one way of doing that which i do not recommend is to randomly take two coordins (x,y) and check if the space(x-radius until x+radius and the same for y) is empty, to check that you need to compare it with all the other nodes stored in the program. That idea is bad so i would suggest to find another way of doing that. Having a list and dragging the new nodes would be nice, something like the SceneBuilder tools list.

Comment: Meaning? what do you mean for the list and then drag the new nodes?

Comment: Using SceneBuilder, how exactly do you add components to the Stage? by selecting a component from a list and dragging to a pane. So a option would be to have a list containing all the components that are able to be added to your pane and then by selecting them and dragging them from the list to a specific place on a pane you can create new nodes. It's like adding a new file to a folder by drag and drop.

Comment: It's a good idea but I have no idea how to make it, more than anything I have little experience in creating the layout of the list, while the logic is clear now.

Comment: Anyway I'm having trouble erasing a runtime node, but I've managed to do it but after a node happens to move it to another location but the associated arch remains fixed and does not move ... you can give me a hand? Here is the link of the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671752/delete-runtime-node-javafx This is the situation 1) https://ibb.co/dxSi6G
2) https://ibb.co/kPCGRG
3) https://ibb.co/hxQs0b   Then if you know there is another problem, the arc between two nodes crosses the letter (see the screenshot), could you avoid the line going through the letter?